# UWP clicking button within a listview

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to do some basic UI and binding in UWP to get my head wrapped around it but I'm having trouble accessing a button within a listview item.

I have a Button where on clicking it, it creates a new object which is added to my ObservableCollection which then ends up adding a new item in my ListView

XMAL

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind counts}" x:Name="buttonsView" Margin="5,0" Background="White" Foreground="#FF5059AB">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Counter">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CountValue, Mode=TwoWay}" FontWeight="Black"/>
                    <Button Click="Increment_Click"  Content="Increment"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

C#

```
public class Counter
{
    private int count;

    public Counter()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    public int CountValue
    {
        get
        {
            return count;
        }
        set
        {
            count = value;
        }
    }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<Counter> counts = new ObservableCollection<Counter>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Increment_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         // ?
    }

    private void AddCounter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        counts.Add(new Counter());
    }
}
```

That works.

But when I click on the button within the StackPanel, the Increment_Click method is called but I'm not sure what to do at that point. I would like to access the Counter object by getting the index of the ListView item and using that to index into the ObservableCollection.

How do I figure out what the index is of the ListView item that was added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of an event you should use `Command` and `CommandParameter`. You would then bind the `Command` to a command implemented in `Counter` and `CommandParameter` to the item (like `{Binding}`).

However, you can achieve your goal with `Click` event as well using `DataContext`:

```
private void Increment_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var button = (Button)sender;
     var counter = (Counter)button.DataContext;
     //...
}
```

Basically `DataContext` is by default inherited from the parent unless you specify otherwise, so in this case `DataContext` is the current list item.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I also implemented binding a command and got that working. Why is that method preferred?

Comment: It is preferred because the MVVM pattern advocates having or business logic separate from the view. That in ideal world means that the view code-behind should be empty (except for the page constructor). Of course this is not achievable in 100 percent of cases, but if you have the option of having a command on the items themselves, it Is better. Another advantage is that you can any time change the command instance and perform a different action (for example based on current state of the item) and it is all transparent to the view.